# Keras / Tensorflow suspected memory leak

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, memory-leaks

I am using Keras (2.4) with Tensorflow (2.3.1) backend. I am tuning some meta-parameters with grid-search so there are multiple calls to model creation and `model.fit` method (the training is done on a machine with a single GPU).

Tensorflow has a documented memory leak issue ([e.g see here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33030) but there are more reports, just search Google for `tensorflow memory leak`). I've encountered the issue in the past and managed to keep it at a minimal level using a combination of small batch size and calling Python's garbage collector manually. But now on a different project I suspect I am encountering it again.

I'm attaching an image of monitoring RAM usage over approx. 15 hours, and my question is simple - does it look like it can be the result of a memory leak? On one hand, the maximal usage grows with time. But, on the other hand, it seems that de-allocation (maybe when model instance is destroyed and created with new parameters?) frees most of the used memory back (almost) to the initial level.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

How about `tf.keras.backend.clear_session()`
Follow the [document](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.3/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/clear_session)

> Keras manages a global state, which it uses to implement the
> Functional model-building API and to uniquify autogenerated layer
> names.
>
> If you are creating many models in a loop, this global state will
> consume an increasing amount of memory over time, and you may want to
> clear it. Calling clear_session() releases the global state: this
> helps avoid clutter from old models and layers, especially when memory
> is limited.

Comment: Thanks, it is helpful for dealing with it, but in addition I want to know if the pattern in the attached image looks like a memory leak.

Comment: The memory has  an upward tendency on the whole. BTW, I want to know if the RAM usage in the attached image only comes from this training process？

Comment: No, I just did a simple total RAM monitoring. But there is no other process I am running as a user (I mean, as opposed to the OS's processes)

Comment: I am sure no other process is consuming significant memory (I verified that manually)